Flutter DropdownMenu goes out of bounds when enableFilter is on
tl;dr
With filtering on, I get out-of-bounds errors in my DropdownMenu and I can't figure out why.
I'm learning Flutter. My DropdownMenu crashes with RangeError Index out of range if I select anything other than the first entry in the drop down AND enableFilter: true, is set. It does not do this with enableFilter: false.
Things I've tried:

Made sure I have an entry for every selection in the LevelOfBadness enum.
Logged the data to make sure the values are okay. The values look appropriate to me, both type and value.
Googled for help: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/154532 which doesn't seem to directly apply, but:
Googled for help: Flutter DropDownMenu (RangeError (length): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0) which may be a different aspect of the same issue.

Can someone help me understand either:

What is going on, and if it relates to the StackOverflow issues above

--or--

What have I done wrong?

import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageFive extends StatefulWidget
{
  const PageFive({super.key});
  
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState()
  {
    return PageFiveState();
  } 
}

enum Villian { Gargamil, Doofenschmirtz, Kinderlumper }
enum LevelOfBadness {I, II, III, IV, V, X}

class PageFiveState extends State
{
  Villian? theBiggestVillian;
  LevelOfBadness? selectedBadnessRating;
  TextEditingController tfc = TextEditingController();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber[200] ,
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: const Text("This is light red"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red[300]),
          body:
           Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
           child: Row (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent)),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const Text("Choose a Villian"),
                        RadioListTile<Villian> (
                          tileColor: Colors.blue,
                          title: Text(Villian.Gargamil.name),
                          groupValue: theBiggestVillian,
                          value: Villian.Gargamil,
                          onChanged: (Villian? newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                            theBiggestVillian = newValue;
                          });
                          },
                        ),
                        RadioListTile<Villian> (
                          tileColor: Colors.green,
                          title: Text(Villian.Doofenschmirtz.name),
                          groupValue: theBiggestVillian,
                          value: Villian.Doofenschmirtz,
                          onChanged: (Villian? newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                            theBiggestVillian = newValue;
                          });
                          },
                        ),
                        RadioListTile<Villian> (
                          tileColor: Colors.orange,
                          title: Text(Villian.Kinderlumper.name),
                          groupValue: theBiggestVillian,
                          value: Villian.Kinderlumper,
                          onChanged: (Villian? newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                            theBiggestVillian = newValue;
                            log(theBiggestVillian.toString());
                          });
                          },
                        ),

                        const Spacer(),
                        const Text("Select a Badness Rating"),
                        DropdownMenu(
                          // enableFilter: true, // If I turn this on, I get out of bounds exceptions whenever I select anything but the first entry. Why?
                          onSelected: (currentBadnessSelectedInDropdownMenu) {
                            if (currentBadnessSelectedInDropdownMenu !=null)
                            {
                              setState(() 
                              {
                                log("Type is: " + currentBadnessSelectedInDropdownMenu.runtimeType.toString());
                                log("Value is: " + currentBadnessSelectedInDropdownMenu.toString());
                                selectedBadnessRating = currentBadnessSelectedInDropdownMenu;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          dropdownMenuEntries: const <DropdownMenuEntry<LevelOfBadness>>[
                          DropdownMenuEntry(value: LevelOfBadness.I, label: "Underwhelming"),
                          DropdownMenuEntry(value: LevelOfBadness.II, label: "Rookie"),
                          DropdownMenuEntry(value: LevelOfBadness.III, label: "Moderate"),
                          DropdownMenuEntry(value: LevelOfBadness.IV, label: "Fully-Operational"),
                          DropdownMenuEntry(value: LevelOfBadness.V, label: "Level 5 Baddie"),
                          DropdownMenuEntry(value: LevelOfBadness.X, label: "Mega-baddie!"),
                        ],
                      ),

                        const Spacer(),
                        const Text("Type a Characteristic"),
                          TextField(
                            controller: tfc,
                            onChanged: textFieldChangedCallback,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                              hintText: 'Write something here',
                            ),
                          ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        ],
                      ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.greenAccent)),
                child: SizedBox(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        const Spacer(),
                        const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 150,
                          child: Text("Our villian, ${theBiggestVillian?.name??""}, is of calibre $selectedBadnessRating. Most folks would describe them as ${tfc.value.text}. In conclusion, don't be a villian."),
                          ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        Row( 
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            ElevatedButton(onPressed: onPressedSubmit, child: const Text("Submit")),
                            // Spacer(), // if I put a Spacer() here, I get unbounded size! Grr.
                            ElevatedButton(onPressed: onPressedReset, child: const Text("Reset")),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

void onPressedSubmit()
{
setState(() {
    // todo
  });
}

void onPressedReset()
{
  setState(() {
    tfc.text = "";
    theBiggestVillian = null;
    // selectedBadnessRating = null; // This doesn't do what I want yet either. I want to be able to deselect the item....
    log("Reset ran");
  });
}

void textFieldChangedCallback(String newValue)
{
  setState(() {});
}

}




Note that if I use the filter e.g. by typing on the keyboard, it seems to work without crashing, but if I use the mouse to select the option, it crashes.

You need to provide filtercallback when enabledFilter:true
child: DropdownMenu<LevelOfBadness>(
  enableFilter: true,
  filterCallback: (entries, filter) {
    return entries;
  },


Oh my. That was super simple. Thank you!

Glad to help, you can find more on attached doc
